# Javascript setInterval not working properly

Tags: javascript

I created a .js file in my website and I'm running some function to save the `scrollTop` value of `ul`. I have another function that's being called with `setInterval`, to restore the `scrollTop` value if it jumped back to 0 (Because I use an ajax method; it gets updated every 5 seconds and jumps to the top).

The problem is that `chatScroll`, which is a global variable in the .js file, gets reset after the ajax method has been called.

These are my Javascript functions:

```
var chatScroll = 0, chattimer = false;
function UpdateChatScroll(chat) {
    if (chat.scrollTop != 0 && chat.scrollTop != chatScroll) {
        //window.alert(chat.scrollTop);
        chatScroll = chat.scrollTop;
        if (!chattimer) {
            chattimer = true;
            setInterval(function () { RestoreChatScroll(chat); }, 10000);
        }
    }
}
function RestoreChatScroll(chat) {
    //window.alert(chatScroll);
    if (chat.scrollTop == 0) {
        window.alert("Should update..");
        chat.scrollTop = chatScroll;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this fixable?

Comment: I'm not sure it gets reset, but it won't set the scroll back. It sends the `window.alert("Should update..")` but won't really update anything..

Comment: It's fine, the variable `chatScroll` stays the same because there's just an async postback. It just doesn't execute this command: `chat.scrollTop = chatScroll;`

Comment: I already fixed it. `chat` wasn't a global variable so it was reset after postback. It works now, though not entirely smooth.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fix:

```js
var chatScroll = 0, chattimer = false, chatVar, chattimervar;
function UpdateChatScroll() {
    clearInterval(chattimervar);
    chatVar = document.getElementById("msgs_list");
    if (chatVar.scrollTop != chatScroll) {
        chatScroll = chatVar.scrollTop;
        chattimervar = setInterval(RestoreChatScroll, 10);
    }
}
function RestoreChatScroll() {
    chatVar = document.getElementById("msgs_list");
    if (chatScroll != chatVar.scrollTop) {
        chatVar.scrollTop = chatScroll;
    }
}
```